# How to handle a double click on a TabControl's tabs panel's empty space?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

In a TabControl there can be empty place to the right from tabs in the panel if there are not too many tabs. When a user doubleclicks in this empty space I'd like to process this event to create a new tab. How to achieve this?

Comment: You could add a button, anchored top-right and position it in the z-order above the `TabControl`. A button is _way_ more intuitive to use. I've just removed a similar function to what you trying to do, because no one discovered it :-)

Comment: What happens when there *are* too many tabs?

Comment: "You could add a button..." - good idea, I'll try. "no one discovered it" - may be you're right saying statistically (for me doubleclicking on empty space to create a tab was always the most natural way). "What happens when there are too many tabs?" - In my application tabs are the functionality meant (by the subject) for a very humble use, I suppose approximately 80% of users to never use tabs and approximately 95% to never use more than 6 tabs.

Comment: I completely disagree that it's intuitive to click on an empty space to create something new. I've never once thought to try on my own that in any application. And I consider myself somewhat of a "power" user, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't sound like a UI concept that's intuitive to the users of your application. Why don't you add a small additional tab labelled "+". When the user clicks on that tab, the full tab is added. Firefox does it that why and it was intuitive to me from the first second.

(Sorry for not answering your double click question.)

Comment: +1 Not answering the question was the right thing to do in this case. Discoverability is *extremely* important in UI design, and adding a button also solves the problem of the feature *disappearing* when "too many" tabs are already in the control.